# PlayFramework 2.1.5 / Java / Action not found

Tags: java, playframework

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                   controllers.Application.index()

# Tasks
GET     /tasks              controllers.Application.tasks()
POST    /tasks              controllers.Application.newTask()
POST    /tasks/:id/delete   controllers.Application.deleteTask(id: Long)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/tasks/2/delete
```

The error:

```
Action not found

For request 'GET /tasks/2/delete'
These routes have been tried, in this order:

1 GET   /                          controllers.Application.index()
2 GET   /tasks                     controllers.Application.tasks()
3 POST  /tasks                     controllers.Application.newTask()
4 POST  /tasks/$id<[^/]+>/delete   controllers.Application.deleteTask(id:Long)
5 GET   /assets/$file<.+>          controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public", file:String)
```

The HTML fragment:

```
<form action="/tasks/2/delete" method="POST" >
   <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

I don't understand why the rule #4 can't apply.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally complete myself the POST request to add the missing id:

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[Task])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {
    <h1>@tasks.size() task(s)</h1>
    <ul>
    @for(task <- tasks) {
        <li>
        @task.label
        @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
            <input type="hidden" id="id" value="@task.id"><!-- *** added ***-->
            <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        }
        </li>
    }
    </ul>

    <h2>Add a new task</h2>
    @form(routes.Application.newTask()) {
        @inputText(taskForm("label")) 
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    }
}
```

Resulting HTML is:

```
<form action="/tasks/1/delete" method="POST" >
   <input type="hidden" id="id" value="1">
   <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

The todolist sample of PlayFramework 2.2.0 executed on top of PlayFramework 2.1.5 doesn't work very well...

Answer (score 0):

It says it can't find `GET /tasks/2/delete` because you only defined a route using POST:

```
POST    /tasks/:id/delete   controllers.Application.deleteTask(id: Long)
```

So you have to do a POST request instead of a GET.

Comment: HTML added to my previous post to show it's a POST request, how can I change the way the arguments are transmitted?

Comment: @Aubin The form looks good, should be send as POST as far as I can tell. Maybe some javascript is interfering with the form submit? Try looking in the browser network console to check what actually gets send.